# How can I avoid code duplication?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mapbox

I have the following JQuery code that I'd love to get DRY. At the moment there is only 2 markers but 30+ to follow so I need a clean solution for this:

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'secret_token';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
    .setView([-12.260355, 29.927956], 11);

var geoJson01 = {
    features: [{
        type: 'Feature',
        properties: {
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-symbol': 'embassy',
            video: '<iframe src="http://www.example.com/test1.html" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>',
        },
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [29.91, -12.28]
        }
    }]
};
var geoJson02 = {
    features: [{
        type: 'Feature',
        properties: {
            'marker-size': 'large',
            'marker-symbol': 'embassy',
            video: '<iframe src="http://www.example.com/test2.html" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>',
        },
        geometry: {
            type: 'Point',
            coordinates: [29.81, -12.18]
        }
    }]
};

var myLayer01 = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
var myLayer02 = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

myLayer01.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    var marker = e.layer,
        feature = marker.feature;
    var popupContent =  feature.properties.video;
    marker.bindPopup(popupContent,{
        closeButton: false,
        minWidth: 300,
        maxWidth: 810
    });
});
myLayer02.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    var marker = e.layer,
        feature = marker.feature;
    var popupContent =  feature.properties.video;
    marker.bindPopup(popupContent,{
        closeButton: false,
        minWidth: 300,
        maxWidth: 810
    });
});

myLayer01.setGeoJSON(geoJson01);
myLayer02.setGeoJSON(geoJson02);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `function` can accept argument and can return `object`..

Comment: Have you heard about functions ? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/javascript_functions.htm

Comment: Create an object geoJson, return that from your function to an array of geoJson objects. Retrieve them via index notation as desired

Comment: You can use a `FeatureCollection` instead of different `Feature`s and then adding them all in one `geojson`

Comment: Didn't know about FeatureCollection, will look it up - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

extract out the differences into objects in an array then `forEach` over it:-

```js
var markers = [

  {
    coordinates: [29.91, -12.28],
    video: '"http://www.example.com/test1.html"'
  }, {
    coordinates: [29.81, -12.18],
    video: '"http://www.example.com/test2.html"'
  }

];

L.mapbox.accessToken = 'secret_token';
var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
  .setView([-12.260355, 29.927956], 11);

function setMarker(obj) {

  var geoJson01 = {
    features: [{
      type: 'Feature',
      properties: {
        'marker-size': 'large',
        'marker-symbol': 'embassy',
        video: '<iframe src=' + obj.video + ' frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>',
      },
      geometry: {
        type: 'Point',
        coordinates: obj.coordinates
      }
    }]
  };

  var myLayer01 = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);

  myLayer01.on('layeradd', function(e) {
    var marker = e.layer,
      feature = marker.feature;
    var popupContent = feature.properties.video;
    marker.bindPopup(popupContent, {
      closeButton: false,
      minWidth: 300,
      maxWidth: 810
    });
  });

  myLayer01.setGeoJSON(geoJson01);
}

markers.forEach(function(m) {

  setMarker(m);

})
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
L.mapbox.accessToken = 'secret_token';
    var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'mapbox.streets')
        .setView([-12.260355, 29.927956], 11);

    // new
    var array = [{
        features : [{
            type : 'Feature',
            properties : {
                'marker-size' : 'large',
                'marker-symbol' : 'embassy',
                video : '<iframe src="http://www.example.com/test1.html" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>',
            },
            geometry : {
                type : 'Point',
                coordinates : [29.91, -12.28]
            }
        }]
    }, {
        features : [{
            type : 'Feature',
            properties : {
                'marker-size' : 'large',
                'marker-symbol' : 'embassy',
                video : '<iframe src="http://www.example.com/test2.html" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>',
            },
            geometry : {
                type : 'Point',
                coordinates : [29.81, -12.18]
            }
        }]
    }];

    var layers = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    {
        layers[i] = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map);
        layers[i].on('layeradd', function(e)
        {
            var marker = e.layer,
                feature = marker.feature;
            var popupContent = feature.properties.video;
            marker.bindPopup(popupContent, {
                closeButton : false,
                minWidth : 300,
                maxWidth : 810
            });
        });
        layers[i].setGeoJSON(array[i]);
    }
```

Comment: Not completely DRY yet but that's already a lot of help - thank you! I'll update this answer if I manage to DRY it up even more.